# Disable HTML Warnings in Eclipse for Java EE developers edition

Tags: java, html, eclipse, web-applications, warnings

I am working on a Web App with Eclipse for Java EE. I have JSP files that are built with HTML files as includes. My index.jsp looks like this:

```
<jsp:include page="include/top.html" />
    <title>Title!</title>
<jsp:include page="include/header.html" />
<jsp:include page="include/menu.html" />
      <div class="span-15 prepend-1 last">
        <h6>What is an <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface">API</a>?</h6>
        <p>An application programming interface (API) is an interface that software programs implement in order to allow other software to interact with it; much in the same way that software might implement a User interface in order to allow humans to interact with it.</p>
      </div>
<jsp:include page="include/footer.html" />
```

The problem is with the includes. **footer.html** Looks like this:

```
      <hr />
      <h3 class="alt"><b><a href="/copyright.html">Copyright</a> &copy; 2009</b> My Company. All rights reserved.</h3>
      <hr />
      <p>
        Visit <a href="/">Home</a>
      </p>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which gets put at the bottom of most pages. And I'm really annoyed with these warning messages like `Invalid location of tag (body).` I know its invalid within this file but the other side belongs with header.html.

In Java classes you can suppress warnings with things like `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` ... Any way to do something like this with these HTML or JSP files?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. Right click on your project, `Properties` -> `Validation` (or you can go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Validation` to do this globally).
2. Uncheck "Build" for HTML syntax validation OR
3. Click ellipsis under "Settings" and add a rule to exclude specific file name / extension / what have you

Comment: The project is checked out from Version Control, so it would be nice to suppress these warnings for other users. But this works for me =)

Comment: If you do this per project (as opposed to globally), settings are saved in your `.project` file which you can then check into version control.

Comment: WATCH OUT: Certain plugins override this and no matter what you do under validation, it won't silence it. Personally I had to remove tk.eclipse.plugin.htmleditor before they went away.

Comment: Also note: if you specify a folder in an exclude group rule, it will only exclude the files directly in that directory (and *not* in subdirectories)

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I'm aware of to solve this is to disable HTML validation for the project. Right click the project in question and go to properties, then go to the validation menu. You can either disable all HTML validation or go into the "HTML Syntax" validation sub-menu and disable individual problems.

Answer (score 0):

im using myeclipse and at 
window->preferences->validation->jsp there is bunch of choices

Answer (score 0):

@ChssPly76 is correct, but I'd like to add that (using Mars), after following those steps, I was also required to re-validate the project to remove the warnings in the **Problems** section (right click project, *validate*).

Answer (score 0):

2018-01-07: Eclipse Oxygen.

Things may have changed in this regard since 2009, because what I find at the moment is that you can tweak HTML errors and warnings globally (Window --> Prefs --> Web --> HTML Files --> Validation), or you can tweak on a per-project basis: Project --> Properties --> Validation --> HTML Syntax.

For example I just set Text Regions --> Invalid text string to "Ignore" because I was getting spurious warnings for some Django HTML files with placeholders (or whatever they're called).

I also found that I was getting a warning for the `hidden` attribute in DIVs: "your attribute should be followed by an = character".  Oh dear: in HTML5 `hidden` is a `boolean`, Eclipse is therefore getting this wrong. I therefore set Attributes --> "Missing attribute equals sign character" to "Ignore" as well.